# Transpile python request in Javascript fetch?

Tags: javascript, python, post, authorization, fetch

I was wondering how to write this python request in javascript:

```
url = "something.something"
data = {"name":"description"}
auth = ("user","11111")

x = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=auth)
```

I have this so far:

```
fetch(`something.something`, {
      method: 'POST',
      header: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'user:11111',
      },
      body: {
        "name": "description"
      }
})
```

But I have an 403. My guess is that the authorization is formatted incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
auth = ("user","11111")

x = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=auth)
```

This uses `HTTPBasicAuth` for authorization.

[Basic HTTP Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) requires the credentials to be passed in the `Authorization` header like this:

```
Authorization: Basic <base64(user:password)>
```

So the javascript example should look something like:

```
fetch(`something.something`, {
      method: 'POST',
      header: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('user:11111'),
      },
      body: {
        "name": "description"
      }
})
```